# Topology of $\mathbb R^n$ question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have the following problem:
$\newcommand{Rn}{\mathbb R^n}$
$\newcommand{U}{\bigcup}$
$\newcommand{a}{{a \in A}}$
$\newcommand{b}{{b \in B}}$
$\newcommand{es}{\emptyset}$
$\newcommand{ss}{\subset}$
$\newcommand{sm}{\setminus}$
$\newcommand{d}{\partial}$
$\newcommand{e}{\varepsilon}$

> Let $X \ss \Rn$, and let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint open subsets of $X$ with the subspace topology. Show that there exist disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $\Rn$ such that $U \cap X = A$ and $V \cap X = B$.

My partial solution is as follows:

Since $A$ is open in $X$, for every $\a$ there exists $\e_a > 0$ such that $A = \U_\a \beta_X(a, \e_a)$, where $\beta_X(x, \e)$ is the open ball relative to $X$, centered at $x$, of radius $\e$. Now let $P = \U_\a \beta(a, \e_a)$. Clearly, $P$ is open in $\Rn$ and $P \cap X = A$. Construct $Q$ from $B$ and $X$ in a similar way.

Clearly, $P \cap Q \cap X = A \cap Q = B \cap P = A \cap B = \es$. However, $P \cap Q$ isn't necessarily empty. It is merely guaranteed that their intersection lies outside of $X$, and hence outside of $A$ and $B$. That's why I haven't called them $U$ and $V$ in the first place.

Now, I want to show that $U = P \sm \bar Q$ and $V = Q \sm \bar P$ satisfy the given requirement. Clearly, $U$ and $V$ are both open in $\Rn$, and $U \cap X = (P \sm \bar Q) \cap X = (P \cap X) \sm (Q \cup \d Q) = A \sm \d Q$ (and similarly for $B$ and $V$). I just need to show that $A \cap \d Q = \es$. How do I do this? Or, is my idea completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For every $a \in A,$ $d(a,B)>0.$ Similarly, for every $b \in B,$ $d(b,A)>0.$ Could $B(a,d(a,B)/2)$ ever intersect $B(b,d(b,A)/2)?$

Comment: Plaudits...........

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is false if $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is replaced by a general
topological space (or the metric topology is replaced by an arbitrary
topology).

For example. Let $\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the topology $\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R},\{1\}^{c},\{2\}^{c},\{1,2\}^{c}\}$
and let $X=\{1,2\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Let $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$,
Note that $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $X$ because $A=\{2\}^{c}\cap X$
and $B=\{1\}^{c}\cap X$. Clearly $A\cap B=\emptyset$. However, we
cannot find disjoint open sets $U,V$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A=U\cap X$
and $B=V\cap X$.

Therefore, to prove the proposition (if it is true), one must use
properties of metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Any proof that just uses set-theoretic construction on general setting (without anything specific to the metric topology) must be invalid.

Comment: Thanks. In my real analysis class, we aren't concerned with any topologies on $\mathbb R^n$ other than the one induced by any norm. In my solution attempt, I used open balls, which implicitly requires there to be a metric.

Answer (score 1):

Based on zhw's hints, it seems that the proposition can be generalized to:

Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space and let $Y$ be a subset
of $X$, equipped with the relative topology. Given disjoint open subsets
$A$, $B$ of $Y$ (with respect to the relative topology), there
exist open sets $U,V\subseteq X$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset$ such that
$A=U\cap Y$ and $B=V\cap Y$.

Proof: Choose a metric $d$ for $X$ such that the metric topology
induced by $d$ is the given topology of $X$.

We assert that: (1) For each $a\in A$, $d(a,B)>0$.

Proof of (1): We prove by contradiction. Suppose that there exists
$a\in A$ such that $d(a,B)=0$. Then there exists a sequence in $\{b_{n}\}\subseteq B$
such that $d(a,b_{n})\rightarrow0$. Since $A$ is open in $Y$ and
$a\in A$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(a,\delta)\cap Y\subseteq A$,
where $B(a,\delta):=\{x\mid x\in X\mbox{ and }d(x,a)<\delta\}$. Choose
$n$ such that $b_{n}\in B(a,\delta)$. Note that $b_{n}\in B\subseteq Y$,
so $b_{n}\in B(a,\delta)\cap Y\subseteq A$. This contradicts to $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Similarly, for each $b\in B$, $d(b,A)>0$.

Now, for each $a\in A$,
$b\in B$, let $r_{ab}=\frac{1}{4}\min\left(d(a,B),d(b,A)\right)>0$.
Define $U=\bigcup_{a\in A,b\in B}B(a,r_{ab})$ and $V=\bigcup_{a\in A,b\in B}B(b,r_{ab})$.
Clearly $U,V$ are open and $U\cap Y\supseteq A$, $V\cap Y\supseteq B$.
We assert that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Suppose the contrary that there
exists $x\in U\cap V$, then there exists $a_{1},a_{2}\in A$, $b_{1},b_{2}\in B$
such that $x\in B(a_{1},r_{a_{1}b_{1}})$ and $x\in B(b_{2},r_{a_{2}b_{2}})$.
Now 
$$
d(a_{1},b_{2})\leq d(a_{1},x)+d(x,b_{2})<r_{a_{1}b_{1}}+r_{a_{2}b_{2}}\leq\frac{1}{4}d(a_{1},B)+\frac{1}{4}d(b_{2},A)\leq\frac{1}{4}d(a_{1},b_{2})+\frac{1}{4}d(b_{2},a_{1})=\frac{1}{2}d(a_{1},b_{2})
$$
which is a contradiction because $d(a_1,b_2)>0$. ($A\cap B=\emptyset$, so $a_1\neq b_2$)

Choose open sets $U',V'\subseteq X$ such that $U'\cap Y=A$ and $V'\cap Y=B$.
Define $U_{A}=U\cap U'$ and $V_{B}=V\cap V'$. Then $U_{A}$ and
$V_{B}$ are open subsets of $X$, satisfying $U_{A}\cap V_{B}=\emptyset$,
$U_{A}\cap Y=A$, and $V_{B}\cap Y=B$.

Comment: I have a question: Is it possible to further generalize the proposition? For example, is it true for general $T_4$ topology space? (i.e. Hausdorff + Normal)

Comment: Statement (1) follows immediately from standard results: (a) In a metric space $(X, d)$, we have $d(x, B) = 0$ iff $x \in \text{cls} B$; (b) for subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ and subset $B$ of $Y$, we have $\text{cls}_{Y} B = Y \cap \text{cls}\, B$; and (c) For a subset $Y$ of a metric space $(X, d)$ and for an element $x \in Y$ and $B \subset Y$, we have $d_{Y} (x, B) = d(x, b)$, where $d_{Y}$ is the metric induced on $Y$ by $d$.

Comment: Or, a simpler, more direct proof of (1): Since $A$ is open in $Y$, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ with the ball $B_{\varepsilon} (x, d_{Y}) \subset A$, where $d_{Y}$ is the metric induced on $Y$ by the metric $d$ of $X$. For each $b \in B$, we have $b \notin A$ whence $d(x, b) = d_{Y}(x, b) \geq \varepsilon$. Hence $d(x, B) \geq \varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: You're making this more complicated than necessary. Just put $U=\bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,d(a,B)/2)$ and $V=\bigcup_{b\in B}B(b,d(b,A)/2)$. For any a and b, $d(a,B)/2 + d(b,A)/2 \leq d(a,b)/2 + d(a.b)/2 \leq d(a,b)$ so U and V are disjoint.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan  It is equivalent to the space being hereditarily normal. I've put a proof in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a space X has property P iff For any subspace Y of X and disjoint open sets A, B of Y, there exist disjoint open sets U, V of X such that $A=U\cap Y$ and $ B=V\cap Y$.

X has P iff it is hereditarily normal.

Proof. If C, D are closed disjoint subsets of X, put $Y = C \cup D$. C and D are open in Y so P gives disjoint, open U and V in X with $C \subseteq U$ and $D \subseteq V$, showing X is normal. P is hereditary so X is hereditarily normal.

Conversely, assume X is hereditarily normal and A nad B are disjoint open subsets of a subspace Y. Let A' and B' be open subsets of X such that $A = A' \cap Y$ and $B = B' \cap Y$. Let $Z = A' \cup B'$ and $C = \overline{A}^{Z}$ and $D = \overline{B}^{Z}$. These are disjoint and closed in Z, so as Z is normal there exist U and V open in Z such that $C \subseteq U$ and $D \subseteq V$. But Z is open so U and V are the open sets of X that we require.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be open in $X$. This means that

$$
A= \cup_{i \in I} (A_i \cap X)
$$
where the $A_i$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Hence, 
$$
A= (\cup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap X; \ \ A_i\  \text{open in} \ \ \mathbb{R}^n
$$

Similary,

$$
B = (\cup_{j \in J} B_j) \cap X; \ \ B_j\  \text{open in} \ \ \mathbb{R}^n
$$

$A_i$ and $B_j$ must be pairwise disjoint. If not, assume that $A_{i0}$ and $B_{j0}$ have non-empty intersection. Then

$$
A \cap B = 
 ((\cup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap X) \cap ((\cup_{j \in J} B_j) \cap X) = \\
((\cup_{i \in I} A_i) \cap (\cup_{j \in J} B_j ) \cap X = \\
(\cup_{i \in I, j \in J} A_i \cap B_j) \cap X \\
$$

one of the terms in the union will be which will be $A_{i0} \cap B_{j0} \cap X$, which will be non-empty, and hence $A \cap B \neq \phi$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, all $A_i$ and $B_j$ are mutually disjoint. Therefore, we can pick $U = \cup_{i \in I} A_i$, $V = \cup_{j \in J} B_j$.

$U, V$ open in $\mathbb{R^n}$ since they are union of open set.

$U \cap V = \phi$ since $A_i$ and $B_j$ are pairwise disjoint.

$U \cap X = A$, $V \cap X = B$ by definition.

Comment: Huh?  That $A$ be open in the subspace $X$ means the $A = A_{1} \cap X$ for some *one* open subset $A_{1}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$; similarly for $B$. So I don't understand the purpose of the union of a family of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, it is definitely *not* true in general that $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ are disjoint; that's what you're trying to obtain.

Comment: why? each of the $A_i$ have to be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since they come from the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is because we define the subspace topology of $X$ as the open sets of the original space (in this case, $\mathbb{R}^n$ intersected with $X$. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand why if $A_{i0}\cap B_{j0}$ is not empty, then $A_{i0}\cap B_{j0}\cap X$ is also nonempty?

Answer (score -1):

Your quoted statement seems to be true by definition? If $A \in X$ is open, then there is an open $U \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $A =U\cap X$. See [subspace topology](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). Or otherwise, you shall define openness in subspace another way.

It remains to show $U \cap V =\varnothing$. If not, then remove the common part of $U$ and $V$. Indeed, if we define $U' =U -\overline{U \cap V}$, then $U'$ is open. Similarly $V' =V -\overline{U \cap V}$, and $V'$ is open. Since $U \cap V \cap X =\varnothing$, we see still $A =U' \cap X$ and $B =V' \cap X$.

Comment: If $X$ isn't open in $\mathbb R^n$, then it isn't guaranteed that $A$ and $B$ are open in $\mathbb R^n$, so $U = A$ and $V = B$ won't do.

Comment: (You are right, and sorry I deleted the original wrong answer because I don't want to post twice)

Comment: The question asks for $U$ and $V$ to be disjoint; this is not an automatic consequence of $A$ and $B$ being disjoint.

Comment: If $U \cap V \neq \varnothing$, then remove the common part of $U$ and $V$. If we define $U' =U -\overline{U \cap V}$, then $U'$ is open.

Comment: @Aminopterin: But is $U' \cap X = U$ still?

Comment: I think more work is needed. Although $U\cap V$ is disjoint from $X$, its closure $\overline{U\cap V}$ might meet $X$, and then $U'\cap X$ won't be the same as $U\cap X$.

Comment: I see. Feel free to edit if you have come up with the answer! : )